# Android GCM, ConnectionResult=SERVICE_MISSING_PERMISSION

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I've implemented GCM push notifications in my app according to the documentation, and it works randomly. Usually though, it spews out this error:

```
W/GMPM: Service connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_MISSING_PERMISSION, resolution=PendingIntent{dee6afb: android.os.BinderProxy@c3e3718}, message=null}
```

After this error, it usually starts working after a while.

I haven't found any information about this, but I'd assume something is wrong with my manifest... But it's pretty much exactly the same as on the google-GCM sample.

```
<manifest package="fi.pauli.myapp"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

    <permission
        android:name="fi.pauli.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="fi.pauli.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

    <application
        ...
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
                <category android:name="fi.pauli.myapp"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="fi.pauli.myapp.PushNotificationReceiverService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="fi.pauli.myapp.InstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="fi.pauli.myapp.RegistrationIntentService"
            android:exported="false">
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Help, anyone? :)

Update: My RegistrationIntentService looks like this, and it does get a token each time:

```
public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService
{

    public RegistrationIntentService()
    {
        super("RegistrationIntentService");
    }

    public RegistrationIntentService(String name)
    {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        try
        {
            InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
            String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE);

            if(MainActivity.userData != null ? MainActivity.userData.getId() != 0 : false)
            {
                if(!token.equals(MainActivity.userData.getPush_notification_id()))
                {
                    MainActivity.userData.setPush_notification_id(token);
                    MainActivity.userData.setDeviceOS(2);
                    DataClient.writeFile("userData.json", new Gson().toJson(MainActivity.userData), getApplicationContext());
                    MainActivity.updatePushIdToServer(token);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("RegistrationService", e.getMessage());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats your way of registering with GCM? If you are using GCMRegistrar.register, you will need the GET_ACCONTS permission.

Comment: I'm registering using the RegistrationIntentService, exactly the same as in the google example...

InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
            String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE);

Comment: Oh, and that code goes in the onHandleIntent of the RegistrationIntentService. No error there, I do get the token every time...

Comment: Could it be that since I'm building for Android Marshmallow, I should be asking the user for some permission?

Comment: Ok, this seems to be a problem with the Visual Studio emulators - Even Google's own apps log the same error there, yet push notifications work (most of the time). On my actual devices, I don't have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have this permission more in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Comment: Its only needed if he is registering with GCM via the deprecated GCMRegistrar.register. If he is using GoogleCloudMessaging.register the GET_ACCOUNTS permission is no longer needed.

Comment: Yep, I'm not using those deprecated methods. I tried that permission and it didn't help in my case.